# Is there a way to have a custom name for a docker-compose.yaml file on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a use case where I need to have multiple different `docker-compose.yaml` files with the rails app we are deploying. This is because we are deploying the code in both a web server and a worker environment.

I need a `docker-compose.web.yaml` and a few variations of `docker-compose.worker.yaml` and need to be able to tell elastic beanstalk which one to use, depending on if it's a web server or a worker.

I have tried running a script to rename the files in `.ebextensions` but that doesn't seem to work, because `container_commands` happens after it extracts the archive and it fails before running anything in there because it sees there is no docker-compose file. Whereas `commands` happens before the archive is extracted.

Any tips would be appreciated.